# Bizarre URL issue When connecting to Guardian API

Tags: android, json

I am connecting to the Guardian's News feed to download JSON.  Every now and then I get get back JavaScript and it causes an error.  The URL is stored in a static final string so is always the same.  The url that I see in the debugger is correct for JSON. In fact, if I copy the url out of the debugger expressions window and paste it into a browser, I get back JSON. I don't think the problem is with the Guardian.  I think something in my connection code might be corrupting the url somehow, and the Guardian is sending me JavaScript as a default.  But I really don't know.

Here is the URL that is used in all cases. Notice format-json:

```
static final String GuardianUrl = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?format=json&show-fields=headline%2Cbody%2Cthumbnail%2CtrailText%2ClastModified&date-id=date%2Ftoday&api-key=mykey";
```

Here is the top of their JSON file when it comes back correctly:
      {
       "response":{
        "status":"ok",
        "userTier":"approved",
        "total":203,
        "startIndex":1,
       "pageSize":10,
        "currentPage":1,
        "pages":21,
        "orderBy":"newest",
        "results":[{
        etc.

And this is what I get back when it comes as JavaScript:

```
  09-21 15:00:18.853: E/JSON Parser(22101): Error converting string to json <html><head>  <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>function init(_frm) { if (_frm.sent.value == 0) { _frm.sent.value=1; _frm.submit(); } }</script></head><body onload=init(auth)><form name=auth action='http://192.168.3.1:10080/ui/dynamic/guest-login.html' METHOD=GET><input type=hidden name='mac_addr' value='e0:75:7d:d3:15:0a'><input type=hidden name='url' value='http://content.guardianapis.com/search?format=json&#38show-fields=headline%2Cbody%2Cthumbnail%2CtrailText%2ClastModified&#38date-id=date%2Ftoday&#38api-key=pdva9u6ac2rqsx9a7hexzrv3'><input type=hidden name='ip_addr' value='192.168.3.142'><input type=hidden id=sent value='0'><noscript><input type=submit value='continue'></noscript></form></body></html>  ... etc
```

And this is the code that connects and downloads the file:

```
public String getJSONFromUrl(String _url) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(_url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            //ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return null;
            }

            String line;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }


            if (builder.toString().length()>0)
                   json = builder.toString();
            return json;

        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with your router, not your code. When it doesn't work, the response you are seeing is coming from your router. 
Are you using the guest network feature on a Linksys E4200 by any chance? The response you are getting is the guest login page. 
This may be useful: http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Social-Support/Amazon-com-EA6500-Guest-network-became-inaccessible-after-a/td-p/583866

Comment: That is very interesting.  Great catch! I have a NetGear router and I just reset it and the problem went away!  If it has a guest feature, I'm not using it.   Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: No, sorry - I don't know much about routers to be honest. I just noticed that the response in your error case looked like it was coming from your router and then Googled `http://192.168.3.1:10080/ui/dynamic/guest-login.html`